# Arquivos css no laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

Estou iniciando com o Laravel e não estou sabendo onde colocar os arquivos css, já que não existe a pasta assets, como existe no Laravel 5. Preciso trabalhar com a versão 4, pois a versão do PHP no servidor é antiga e não tenho como mudar. Não encontrei nada no Google que me ajudasse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coloque o seu `css` na pasta `project/public/css/`.

Para chamar no seu arquivo de template blade pode ser assim:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

ou

```
{{ HTML::style( asset('css/app.css') ) }}
```

Comment: E precisa chamar o css em todas as páginas?? Eu costumo usar umas 4 css diferentes, terei que chamar todas em todas as páginas ou existe alguma maneira de chamar apenas uma vez para o projeto todo?

Comment: @AmandaLima, daí você poderia utilizar a estrutura de layout do laravel para isso. Você cria um layout com tudo que vai utilizar e estende ele com a view.

Comment: Muito obrigada!!

Comment: você pode colocar em um arquivo chamado template e nas outras páginas herdar ele usando o extends, na documentação tem todo o passo a passo de como fazer:http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates

Answer (score 3):

Amanda, você só precisa colocá-los na pasta `public` da aplicação.

Você pode criar uma pasta para cada tipo de documento/script que você vai utilizar.

Exemplo:

```
public/css
public/js
```

Eu não costumo a utilizar a função `asset`, pois o caminho gerado ficaria literamente como se a aplicação estivesse em `public`.

Para um arquivo javascript por exemplo que estaria em `public/js` poderiamos fazer sim.

```
public/js/jquery.js
```

Poderia ser inserido no código simplesmente assim:

```
{{ HTML::script('js/jquery.js') }}
```

Comment: Eu também faço assim. Sem a função `asset`.

Comment: @DeeSouza, eu chamaria isso de processamento adicional desnecessário